# javascript count down timer flickering on calling more than once

Tags: javascript

```
function countdown(element, minutes, seconds) {
    // set time for the particular countdown
    var time = minutes*60 + seconds;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        var el = document.getElementById(element);
        // if the time is 0 then end the counter

        if(time == 0) {
            //el.innerHTML = "countdown's over!";
         // document.getElementById("timer").style.visibility="hidden";
            clearInterval(interval);
            return;
        }
        var hour=Math.floor( time / (60*60) );
        if (hour < 10) hour = "0" + hour;
        var minutes = 0;
        if(time>=60 && hour>0)
            minutes=Math.floor( (time / 60 )-60);
        else{
            minutes=Math.floor( (time / 60 ));
        }
        if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;
        var seconds = time % 60;
        if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds; 
      //  var text = hour+":"+minutes; //+ ':' + seconds;
        var text = minutes; //+ ':' + seconds;

        el.innerHTML = text;
        time--;
    }, 1000);
}
```

when i am calling the method 2wice, its creating flickering effect.
i.e. `countdown(element, 50, 0);`
it count downs but if i call it again i.e. `countdown(element, 35, 0);` it is flicks showing both the countddowns

Comment: get a jsfiddle going.  How are you displaying this on DOM?

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel the interval when the plugin initializes if you are going to call it on the same element. Otherwise you are running two intervals at once.

I'd suggest returning the interval from your function and allowing yourself to pass that interval in as a parameter. That way you can always cancel the interval before starting it (in case there is already one going). If you pass `null` for the interval var, you can still run `clearInterval()` without throwing errors.

For example:

```
function countdown(element, minutes, seconds, interval) {
    // set time for the particular countdown
    var time = minutes*60 + seconds;
    clearInterval(interval);
    return setInterval(function() {
...
```

Your first call could be:

```
var savedInterval = countdown('some-ele-id', 1, 1, null);
```

And your second call could be:

```
var interval = countdown('some-ele-id', 1, 1, savedInterval);
```

Another solution would be to save the interval as a global variable and cancel it without passing it as a parameter inside your plugin.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to avoid modify your code is:

```
var interval;
...
function countdown(element, minutes, seconds) {
    // set time for the particular countdown
    var time = minutes*60 + seconds;
    interval = setInterval(function() {
...
```

And in your second call:

```
clearInterval(interval);
countdown(element, 35, 0);
```